# Moving PowerPoint callout pointer

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can I move the pointer (the diagonal line) in a callout in PowerPoint 2003?

I want the pointer at the textbox to point to the middle, not the upper third.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the yellow handles and move it. The yellow handles on shapes usually alter the geometry, eg the size and shape of an arrow head, or the radius of a rounded corner. Here it alters the position of the pointer line relative to the box.

Comment: Nope. The far left yellow handle moves were the pointer points. The yellow handle closest to the textbox moves the textbox.

Comment: AH, now you tell us you're using 2003. The behaviour I described is what it does in 2007 and 2010, and yes, I confirm mine does the same as yours in 2003.
Why not just draw a box and a line, and start the line from one of the anchor pioints on the box. When it goes red that means it is locking to that point. You end up with a box and line that move with each other, just like a callout.

You can either draw an autoshape box (which means you don't have to use a rectangle), and use the right click > add text method to use it as a text box, or a text box and format it with a border, fill etc. HTH

Comment: Yep. Just did that, it's a bit annoying when moving the boxes, but once the layout is correct it does look much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Matthew, on PowerPoint 2003 you can't modify where the callout line meets the text box. It's exactly as you state on your blog,

> The left diamond moves where the pointer points, and the right diamond moves the entire textbox.

That's it, sorry.